# Are there pairs of connected graphs that always fail the k-wl test for any k?

Tags: graphs

Is there a pair of connected graphs for which the k-wl test always fails (= judges isomorphic when not isomorphic) for any k? If so, please give an example.

How about the following image? Are they non-isomorphic? I'm not sure...
[image]

---

now i got they are non-isomorphic.
so then, does this correspond to the pair the question asks for?

Comment: "judges isomorphic when non-isomorphic" makes no sense to me. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Pick any two non-isomorphic $n$-vertex $r$-regular graphs.

Edit to address follow-up question. Yes, the two graphs in your figure are $k$-wl for all $k$, and yes, they are non-isomorphic.

One of the graphs has an induced $C_4$ and the other does not.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i added an image now